# How can I estimate the drag of a CAD model?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, drag, estimation, aerodynamics

I have a CAD model that I’m trying to optimize for hydrodynamic-ness, programmatically (preferably with Python).

Is there a way I can find or estimate the drag force of the model, without having the drag coefficient of the shape? I need to be able to compare to models and determine which is more hydrodynamic.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe you could possibly solve the problem numerically using methods such as Finite Element Method (FEM), Boundary Element Method (BEM) or other similar methods. To the best of my knowledge, the problem falls under the hood of the Computational Fluid Dynamics (CFD) for which there are various available solutions, both open-source (of which I hope some will be in Python) as well as proprietary software. I believe this question is better suited for the Engineering StackExchange (https://engineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Probably related, if not a dupe of, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/273292/25301

Comment: Also, hydrodynamics codes do exist in Python, but unless they're using Cython, they're going to be slower than ones written in C/C++ or Fortran. You might want to expand your horizons on the language constraint.